# JSON atribuido via JS a um <select>

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde. Utilizo uma busca com resposta em JSON para um campo UF e Cidade. Para recuperar as cidades pela UF com o JSON, utilizo esse código em JS.

```
$('select[id=uf]').change(function () { // ativa a função quando é selecionado uma UF pelo id = uf
var uf = $(this).val(); // recebe o valor da UF

$.get('/get-cidades', {uf : uf}, function (busca) { // pesquisa pela url com a rota /get-cidades/uf-selecionada
    $('select[name=cidades]').empty(); // procura o campo com o name = cidades
    $.each(busca, function (key, value) {
        $('select[name=cidades]').append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.name + '</option>'); // add os option
    });
});});
```

Até aí tudo bem, tudo funciona corretamente.
O select que recebe as cidades encontradas é de multseleção, então para não deixar o campo no estilo original do HTML, eu utilizo uma extenção do jquery.

```
$('#cidades').multiselect({
numberDisplayed: 0,
includeSelectAllOption: true, });
```

O problema é que quando adiciono essa extenção do jquery, eu não recebo mais os valores no campo cidades, o campo fica sem opção. Vou colocar 2 imagens demonstrando o que ocorre.

Sem o jquery.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o jquery.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendChild is not a function. Está ocorrendo isso no log

Comment: qual a pagina da documentacao dessa extensao que voce ta usando?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Tem mais um script tbm, mas eu não tenho o caminho.

Comment: No caso essa eh a principal do seu problema...